# Why a Private Key of Certificate needed at Client Application While Consuming a WCF Service?

Tags: .net, wcf, certificate, x509certificate

**Scenario**

**X.509 Certificate:** a certificate is provided by the organization for server-client authentication. That certificate serves both purpose server and client authentication.

**WCF Service:** a WCF service is hosted in IIS up and running on a dev server. It secured by an X.509 pfx certificate (provided by organization, not self-signed). It uses message security in its config. `.Pfx` cert is successfully imported on the dev server via mmc at Local Computer in Personal-> Certificate and Trusted Root Certification Authorities-> Certificate

**Client:** it uses the same binding structure as the service. The `.cer` file (of same certificate used on the dev server) is imported at my local in in Personal-> Certificate and Trusted Root Certification Authorities-> Certificate.

**Service config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
            minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
    <services>
        <service name="WCF_HOST.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="customBehaviour">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:57104/Service1" />
                    <!--<add baseAddress = "http://****:57104/Service1" />-->
               </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint
                address=""
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="customWsHttpBinding"
                contract="WCF_HOST.IService1">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint 
                address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="customWsHttpBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
                <!--<readerQuotas
                       maxDepth="2147483647"
                       maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                       maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                       maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                       maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />-->
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="customBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                     <serviceCertificate findValue="tempCert"
                             storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
                             x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                     <clientCertificate>
                         <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" 
                             revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                     </clientCertificate>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="customWsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint 
        address="http://****:57104/Service1.svc" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="customWsHttpBinding" 
        behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior" 
        contract="ServiceClient.IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="tempCert"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="he f5 l9 f9 41 e1 f5 ea 20 ef 55 bc 99 4c ca 5b c4 c5 31 d9" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
            <clientCertificate 
              findValue="tempCert"
              storeLocation="CurrentUser" 
              storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Certificate description**

[image]

**Questions**

1. When I try to consume the service at `webmethod` invocation it throws an exception

   > The certificate 'CN=tempCert, OU=***19, O=****Inc., C=SG' must have a private key. The process must have access rights for the private key

   Why does the client application expect a private key here?
2. If I provide the same `.pfx` certificate (used on the server) to the client app, it worked. How and why?
3. Wasted umpteen hours on the issue, any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mutual SSL (client certificate) of course requires you to have access to private key by definition, or such connections cannot be created at all. Do learn the very basic things from a book or tutorial.A `.cer` file usually contains only the public key, and you need `.pfx` to import both private/public keys.

Comment: In a multiple clients scnerio do we need multiple .pfx certs ?

Comment: it depends on whether you want to distinguish different clients from each other.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bradleycotier/2011/12/14/mutual-authentication-with-a-iis-hosted-wcf-data-service-installed-in-a-workgroup-environment/ ..says : "in order for the client and service to successfully converse using certificates, the WCF client app must have access to the client’s private key and IIS (the receiving party) must have access to the client’s public key. Conversely, IIS must have access to the service private key and the client must have access to the service public key".

Comment: So to distinguish clients from each other I need to import their public certs i.e .cer files on server for mutual auth to work. that way the server mmc console will be flooded with client certs.. isn't ? Any alternate ?

Comment: Ques shud be linked not duplicate

Comment: essentially you asked the same question on how mutual SSL works, and any good enough WCF book or similar would give enough insights on that. Without studying the basic concepts in a systematic way, your questions would be endless.

Comment: A ques or two and multiple client scenerios don't feature there. Anyways ,thanks for suggestion on the thread.